# How should I call my DAL in a ASP.NET Core Web Api project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web Api project with Full Framework as EF Core still doesn't support stored procedure mapping and complex type generation.

So my DAL relies on on EF6 against .net 4.6.1.

I built a data access service IDatabaseService which exposes all allowed DB operations, and added it as scoped service in Startup.cs:

```
public interface IDatabaseService
{
    IReadOnlyList<Product> GetAllProducts();
}

public class DatabaseService: IDatabaseService
{
    private readonly WebApiDataProvider provider;

    public DatabaseService(IOptions<ApiSettings> options)
    {
        this.provider = new WebApiDataProvider(options.Value.DbConnectionString); // provider creates a new DbContext here
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return this.provider.GetAllProducts().ToList(); // provider calls the GetAllProducts stored proc method on the created context here
    }
}
```

My problem is now how to deal with this in my controller. On the one hand I should prefer asynch operations to not block the request thread pool so it can return and serve other requests. On the other hand I should not wrap synchronous operations with Task.Run(). So what is the best way to go for:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDatabaseService databaseService;

    public ProductController(IDatabaseService databaseService)
    {
        this.databaseService = databaseService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public Task<ActionResult<Product>> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return this.Ok(this.databaseService.GetAllProducts());
        });
    }
}
```

or

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDatabaseService databaseService;

    public ProductController(IDatabaseService databaseService)
    {
        this.databaseService = databaseService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return this.Ok(this.databaseService.GetAllProducts());
    }
}
```

Or should I do it completely different and declare my service method

```
Task<List<Product> GetAllProducts();
```

so this can be awaited for? Tbh I started this way but from my point of view the only difference here is that I wrap the synchronous DB call one level deeper.

To summarize my question:

- I would appreciate to perform my DB calls async to be able to serve other requests in the mean time
- I feel like using Task.Run() might be not the best way to achieve this
- So what is the best pattern here?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Or you change to EFCore, or you have to use the Full Framework project, which doesn't run on .Net Core.

Comment: I already use the Full Framework. So you suggest if so, declare my actions non-async?